# Does PostGIS/pgrouting actually come with street info?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I've been looking at getting a new GIS setup going, involving QGIS/PostgreSQL/PostGIS/pgrouting, and so far it has been relatively easy. One thing I want to be able to do is to work out travel times, but before I go ahead and learn all the SQL I want to know, does PostGIS/pgrouting actually come with street info? It seems a bit optimistic that they would contain street directories for the entire world, so my question is where does one actually get that info? Are there open source databases available that contain that kind of information?

Also, I really only need Australian data, but being a data junky I won't say no to anything extra :D.

Answer (score 4):

postgres is just the db engein. postgis is binary file which contains a lot of geometry functions. pgrouting is another library with some known algorithems sach as Dijkstra. anyway, non of them include the map. you need to download .osm file (see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) of the cuntry you want and then use osm2pgrouring or osm2postgres to import the .osm file into the db.

Answer (score 3):

A rather simple solution would be to download australia.osm.pbf from http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/australia-oceania/

The data can easily be loaded into PostGIS using osm2po. Follow e.g. http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/an-osm2po-quickstart/